# Is it possible to test Offer Codes in TestFlight

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

I am developing an app using React Native Expo.

I want to implement a promo code that will give users more free trial period for subscriptions. I made a button in my app that redirects users to this link [https://apps.apple.com/redeem?ctx=offercodes&id={apple_app_id}&code](https://apps.apple.com/redeem?ctx=offercodes&id=%7Bapple_app_id%7D&code) where they could enter their promo code (Offer Code). I am using RevenueCat for subscription.

Can somebody explain to me where I am making a mistake?

I tried making One-Time Use Codes and publishing app on TestFlight, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple Promo codes are only available to test in production mode. So you can submit app for review and set the release date in the future and then can test it before it's available to users.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/70426